# find difference beetwwen timestamps in JS and PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, timestamp

I have a problem with count differnce beetween two timestapms. When page loads, I set the value input like:

```
$test_start.val(new Date().getTime()); //e.g. equal to 1424157813
```

Then I submit form by ajax, in handler php script I get `time()` , what equal e.g. to `1424157806949`, so how you can see in php timestamp is longer, and this:

```
function diffTime($endTime, $spendTime)
{
    $diff = $endTime - $spendTime;
    $years = floor($diff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));
     $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60 * 24));
    $hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $days * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60));
   $minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $days * 60 * 60 * 24 - $hours * 60 * 60) / 60);
   $seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $days * 60 * 60 * 24 - $hours * 60 * 60 - $minutes * 60));
   $time = $hours . "hours, " . $minutes . "minutes, " . $seconds . "seconds";

   return $time;
 }
```

And it return e.g. 7 hours etc. So how I can solve this? Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Comment: JS timestamp is in milliseconds, PHP's is in seconds. You have to multiply PHP's one by 1000 or divide JS's one by 1000.

Comment: @AndreiNikolaenko, that a good comment, please make it as answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS timestamp is in milliseconds, PHP's is in seconds. You have to multiply PHP's one by 1000 or divide JS' one by 1000.